# How can I solve a Memory Error when using DataFrameMapping?

Tags: python, dataframe, out-of-memory

Hi I have the following code and for some reason I am getting a memory error - is it something in the code?

```
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
createTrainingAndValidation(finalDf, 'words')
data = finalDf[['between_count','words']]
mapper = DataFrameMapper([
    (['between_count'], None),
    ('words',CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1)))
])
X=mapper.fit_transform(data)
print (X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Memory error suggests that you have exceeded the memory capacity of your system, for example with a multi GB data set. Perhaps CountVectorizer may be exploding the size? A different, more powerful machine might be called for. Alternatively, you might be able to make your operations more memory efficient with multiprocessing, fewer copying operations, et cetera.

Finally, out-of-memory `pandas` is the goal of the `Dask` project. Check 'em out: https://dask.org/, they may have a pattern that can get to your goal.

If all of that fails and you are still unable to fit your work in memory, `pyspark` may be for you. It's a project oriented toward distributed data and ML ops.